# .Net 2/3.5 vs .Net 4/4.5 response time

Tags: .net, shared-hosting, pagespeed

I've been testing my response times on 1&1 Windows shared Hosting.

I have been shocked to discover that a simple ASP.net Hello World response time :

.Net 2/3.5 : stable 350 ms - pretty acceptable to me

.Net 4/4.5 - 600 ms at the best, 2000 ms+ medium response time.

the request is being sent every 5 minutes. I think it's measuring the time to first byte. (the site I use is [Pingalive.com](http://www.pingalive.com))

if anyone is interested in pinging my site (hello world aspx) to test if the performance is acceptable: [my test site](http://www.test.utranslate.fr/) please not, it does load up fast to the naked eye, but runing tests for a few days and comparing results against 2/3.5 is less than promising..

I'm still awaiting response from their support, but I doubt getting anything constructive.

Could a IIS pool on .net 4.5 be that much less responsive than on 2/3.5? 
if not, what on earth could their IT administrators be doing to IIS or pool settings to degrade this performance for one .net version but not for another?

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" %>

<script runat="server">
Sub Page_Load(Sender As Object, E As EventArgs)
HelloWorld.Text = "Hello World!"
End Sub
</script>

<html>
<head>
<title>ASP.NET Hello World</title>

</head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF">

<p><asp:label id="HelloWorld" runat="server" /></p>

</body>
</html>
```